# How to append heading id of an accordion as a anchor url in the browser's address bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have integrated a nice second party accordion (Reference URL: http://www.switchroyale.com/vallenato/) into my website which can't display `h1 ID` as an anchor url by default.

The js code of the accordion is as following:

```
/*!
 * Vallenato 1.0
 * A Simple JQuery Accordion
 *
 * Designed by Switchroyale
 * 
 * Use Vallenato for whatever you want, enjoy!
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
    $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

    //Set The Accordion Content Width
    var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
    $('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

    //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
    $('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
    $('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

    // The Accordion Effect
    $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
        if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
            $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }

        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

and example of `html` code is as following:

```
<body>
<div id="accordion-container">
  <h1 class="accordion-header" id="tab1">What is it?</h1>           
     <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>Some texts goes here</p>
     </div>         
  <h1 class="accordion-header" id="tab2">Download</h1>          
      <div class="accordion-content">
         <p>Some other texts goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to bind the `h1 ID` (Here `"tab1"` and `"tab2"` are `h1 IDs` in the above `html` code) with click function of `js` code so that the heading id of the accordion append as an anchor url in the address bar of a web browser whenever the heading is clicked in order to open the associated tab like the following example?

http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html#tab1

http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html#tab2

Thanks,

Comment: why do you need to do this(www.somesite.com/somepage.html#tab1)? Can you explain? Are you trying to remember which tab is clicked or wants to navigate to another page when the header is clicked?

Comment: if you are try like this <a href="#tab1"><h1 class="accordion-header" id="tab1">What is it?</h1> </a>  ,you will get www.somesite.com/somepage.html#tab1

Comment: @madi i want to have unique url for each tab

Comment: @Manoj adding `href` attribute that way to heading tag causes the accordion loses it's functionality. the anchored url appear in the browser's address bar but the associated tab doesn't open in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code that handles the click event is the following. You have got to amend the codes accordingly. But before you do that, try doing the one suggested below.

```
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
        if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
            $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }

        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }
    });
```

If you want the url to be such, you make the header as a link (My idea):

```
<div id="accordion-container">
  <a class="accordion-header" href="#tab1"><h1 id="tab1">What is it?</h1></a>           
     <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>Some texts goes here</p>
     </div>         
   <a class="accordion-header" href="#tab2"><h1 id="tab2">Download</h1></a>          
      <div class="accordion-content">
         <p>Some other texts goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I did is to give the link the class name as "accordion-header". Please see if this works for you. If this works, perhaps you got to work on the css if any misalignment happens.

Comment: if you need to bind a click, you should bind to the link and not the header.

Comment: adding href attribute that way to heading tag causes the accordion loses it's functionality. The anchored url appear in the browser's address bar but the associated tab doesn't open. thanks anyway.

Comment: You will need to chage the plugin to allow the link to be the activator for the taps. Check if the selector is based on class or the element tag. This will help you to solve the issue. If you still want do without a link, you can try binding an onchange event to a hidden textbox where when the header is clicked, the textbox has the value of the tap and onchange takes care of other logic. You can put the unique url in the textbox if you have any other feature associated to this.

Comment: can you refer me any resource url about this issue? what i expect is, the browser should append the id associated with each tab or heading as anchored url when clicked.

Comment: Silent Pond: You should attempt to read the codes in the plugin and not just hope for answers to come. Not all answers have references.